# Font Family not loading while use CDN in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used CDN and everything working fine except the font-family.

If i removed <%= asset_path "font-family" %> and i load font-family from my app itself, also the font-family not loading. Still im getting same issue.

Comment: Are you using Firefox? If so fonts need to be served with the appropriate CORS headers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw this problem in Firefox and Internet Explorer only. But Chrome working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

- Check if your CDN url is configured properly and your stylesheets are with extension like `styles.css.erb` (only then the <% %> tag will work in a css file)

**Step 2:**

- Check if you have configured property called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your server to enable using Font family from a different domain(CDN domain is considered different domain here)

Please refer the below links for reference

[Link 1](http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/07/fixing-firefox-font-face-cross-domain_25.html)

[Link 2](http://www.lowest-common-denominator.com/2010/01/http_access_control_to_multipl.php)